# Messages an object can respond to vs it can send

Tags: objective-c, messaging

Just a question arising from something I just read in a passage on Protocols contained in a guide to Obj-C from Apple. It says:

"If you know the class of an object, you can look at its interface declaration (and the interface declarations of the classes it inherits from) to find out what messages it responds to. These declarations advertise the messages it can receive. Protocols provide a way for it to also advertise the messages it sends."

I thought that the class interface declares the messages that a class can send also - i.e. not only the messages it can receive? Can someone shed some light on this please?

Comment: Not sure what you mean....  An object that's a view controller subclass sends messages to many objects that are connected to it as outlets in its implementation file.  You wouldn't know that from reading the controller's interface.

Comment: In Short: Protocol meant to define a messages your class can send via delegates. Interface is a definition of the messages tje class can recieve (like a member methods in C++).

Comment: Ok I got it - thanks to you both.